# NUXT Properties from Vuex are not getting updated in DOM when using async actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, store

For demonstration purposes, I created a small test page and store. According to the code, it should show count = 1, then 500ms later count = 2 as the store updates.

Here's my test.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>count = {{ count }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  layout: "test",
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({ count: "test/count" }),
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("test/updateCount");
  },
};
</script>
```

store/test.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  count: 1
});

export const getters = {
  count(state) {
    return state.count;
  }
};

export const actions = {
  updateCount(context) {
    setTimeout(() => {
    context.commit("setCount", 2);
    }, 500);
  }
};

export const mutations = {
  setCount(state, value) {
    state.count = value;
  }
};
```

But the result is always count = 1 in DOM

In vue devtools, both vuex bindings and vuex state show count = 2, but its not updated in DOM.

However, it works if I remove the setTimeout function in actions.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-troubleshoot-store?file=pages/index.vue). Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: I actually figured it out already, I was using automatic google translations to translate my project to english during development, which was probably interfering with it.

Thank you for troubleshooting it.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a Japanese website, so I had google translations turned on during development, which was probably interfering with it. I turned it off and its working now!